# Using lapply over a list of data frames with grouping

Tags: r

I have a list containing two data frames.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- list("seniors" = data.frame(NAME = c("Cletus", "Agnes", "Hank", "Sue", "Maude"),
                                   COOL = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                                   GENDER = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female"),
                                   RACE = c("B", "B", "W", "W", "B")), 
            "juniors" = data.frame(NAME = c("Chester", "Chuck", "Bruce", "Carmen", "Cleo"),
                                   COOL = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                                   GENDER = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female"),
                                   RACE = c("W", "W", "B", "W", "W")))
```

If I want to get counts for a specific grouping variable across both data frames, for example `gender`, grouped by whether or not the individual is `cool` or not, I can use the following code:

```
results <- lapply(names(dat), function(x) {
  dat[[x]] %>% 
    group_by(COOL, GENDER) %>% 
    summarise(TOTAL = n()) %>%
    mutate(COHORT = x) %>% 
    select(COHORT, everything())
})
do.call(rbind, results)
```

However, I want to be able to get counts for more than `n` grouping variables without repeat the code `n` times and to have all results in a single table. Not that while I *always* want to group by `COOL`, the second grouping variable is what would change.

My desired output is as follows (please note that the `TOTAL` figure does not reflect the sample data, I'm mostly just trying to show the desired table structure). Also, I recognize that this table structure doesn't conform to tidy principles, just need it this way for an eventual vlookup in Excel.

```
COHORT    COOL    GROUP_VAR    GROUP_VAL    TOTAL
SENIORS    0      GENDER       MALE         3
SENIORS    1      GENDER       MALE         5
SENIORS    0      GENDER       FEMALE       7
SENIORS    1      GENDER       FEMALE       2
SENIORS    0      RACE         B            2
SENIORS    1      RACE         B            3
SENIORS    0      RACE         W            7
SENIORS    1      RACE         W            9
JUNIORS    0      GENDER       MALE         3
JUNIORS    1      GENDER       MALE         5
JUNIORS    0      GENDER       FEMALE       3
JUNIORS    1      GENDER       FEMALE       1
JUNIORS    0      RACE         B            2
JUNIORS    1      RACE         B            7
JUNIORS    0      RACE         W            3
JUNIORS    1      RACE         W            2
```

I tried wrapping the results list in another lapply wrapper with a list of column names (see below), but that didn't work:

```
group_names <- list("GENDER", "RACE")
lapply(names(dat), function(x) {
  lapply(names(group_names), function (y) {
      dat[[x]] %>% 
    group_by(COOL, y) %>% 
    summarise(TOTAL = n()) %>%
    mutate(COHORT = x,
           GROUP = y) %>% 
    select(COHORT, everything())
  })
})
```

Anybody know how I could do this in an elegant and efficient way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `tibble::enframe()` to convert your list of dataframes to a single dataframe where you can apply your grouping procedure on. Based on the variable names in `dplyr::count()` you specify your grouping variables:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

dat %>% 
  enframe("COHORT", "data") %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  count(COHORT, COOL, GENDER, name="TOTAL")


# A tibble: 7 x 4
  COHORT   COOL GENDER TOTAL
  <chr>   <dbl> <fct>  <int>
1 juniors     0 Female     1
2 juniors     1 Female     1
3 juniors     1 Male       3
4 seniors     0 Female     1
5 seniors     0 Male       1
6 seniors     1 Female     2
7 seniors     1 Male       1
```

Does this answer your question?

=========================================

Based on @DJC comment I propose here a more appropriate solution:

```
dat %>% 
  enframe("COHORT", "data") %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  gather(GROUP_VAR, GROUP_VAL, GENDER, RACE) %>%
  count(COHORT, COOL, GROUP_VAR, GROUP_VAL, name="TOTAL")

# A tibble: 14 x 5
   COHORT   COOL GROUP_VAR GROUP_VAL TOTAL
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>     <int>
 1 juniors     0 GENDER    Female        1
 2 juniors     0 RACE      W             1
 3 juniors     1 GENDER    Female        1
 4 juniors     1 GENDER    Male          3
 5 juniors     1 RACE      B             1
 6 juniors     1 RACE      W             3
 7 seniors     0 GENDER    Female        1
 8 seniors     0 GENDER    Male          1
 9 seniors     0 RACE      B             1
10 seniors     0 RACE      W             1
11 seniors     1 GENDER    Female        2
12 seniors     1 GENDER    Male          1
13 seniors     1 RACE      B             2
14 seniors     1 RACE      W             1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @cholland. It helps, but doesn't exactly achieve the desired result. If you look at my initial post, you'll see that I have a `GROUP_VAR` column which specifies where `GROUP_VAL` comes from. If I add `RACE`, to count in your answer, then I get counts by gender **and** race, rather than counts for each independently :/

Comment: @DJC, I have extended my post

Comment: You're a legend. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches to solve the problem :

1) This is similar to what you were trying doing all the manipulation in each list and then finally bind the rows. We use `imap` here which passes name of the list as well as the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

imap_dfr(dat, ~.x %>%
                 pivot_longer(cols = c(GENDER, RACE)) %>%
                 count(COOL, name, value) %>%
                 mutate(COHORT = .y) %>% 
                 select(COHORT, everything()))

#   COHORT   COOL name   value      n
#   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>  <fct>  <int>
# 1 seniors     0 GENDER Female     1
# 2 seniors     0 GENDER Male       1
# 3 seniors     0 RACE   B          1
# 4 seniors     0 RACE   W          1
# 5 seniors     1 GENDER Female     2
# 6 seniors     1 GENDER Male       1
# 7 seniors     1 RACE   B          2
# 8 seniors     1 RACE   W          1
# 9 juniors     0 GENDER Female     1
#10 juniors     0 RACE   W          1
#11 juniors     1 GENDER Female     1
#12 juniors     1 GENDER Male       3
#13 juniors     1 RACE   B          1
#14 juniors     1 RACE   W          3
```

---

2) For me, this is a better approach than 1) since here we combine the rows of all the list together and do the operation only once on the complete dataframe. This is also much shorter.

```
bind_rows(dat, .id = "COHORT") %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = c(GENDER, RACE)) %>%
   count(COHORT, COOL, name, value)
```